# Apps crashing on OS X Server 10.6 with segmentation fault

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, osx-server, crash

I am running into a strange issue on a web server running OS X Server 10.6.8. Any app I try to open ends up crashing immediately with a segmentation fault. This goes for gui apps like Safari or Calculator, but also command line tools like `xcodebuild`. Apps that are currently running seem to continue running, but no new apps can be launched.

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the crash log for `xcodebuild`:

```
Process:         xcodebuild [38950]
Path:            /Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
Identifier:      xcodebuild
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [38887]

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 10:48:45.110 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000010f0e5400
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f81639 _SCUniverseGetEntryAddress + 76
1   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f876d3 FileIDTree_FindVolumeRecordFromDeviceID + 41
2   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f875ff FileIDTreeGetVRefNumForDevice + 72
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f87547 FSMount::FSMount(unsigned int, FSMountNumberType, short*) + 73
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f85c19 PathGetObjectInfo(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, short*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char*) + 296
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff82f85a48 FSPathMakeRefInternal(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, FSRef*, unsigned char*) + 114
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87799e20 -[NSFileManager directoryContentsAtPath:matchingExtension:options:keepExtension:error:] + 154
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87799d84 -[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:] + 35
8   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010010002c -[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:] + 404
9   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001000fa789 XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded + 3718
10  xcodebuild                      0x000000010000a864 0x100000000 + 43108
11  xcodebuild                      0x0000000100001c04 0x100000000 + 7172
```

Here is a crash log from Calculator.app. As you can see, they bare a lot of similarities (`_SCUniverseGetEntryAddress`, `FileIDTree_FindVolumeRecordFromDeviceID`, etc).

```
Process:         Calculator [39201]
Path:            /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
Identifier:      Calculator
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [65837]

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 10:52:46.112 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000011fb9d800
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f81639 _SCUniverseGetEntryAddress + 76
1   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f876d3 FileIDTree_FindVolumeRecordFromDeviceID + 41
2   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f875ff FileIDTreeGetVRefNumForDevice + 72
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f87547 FSMount::FSMount(unsigned int, FSMountNumberType, short*) + 73
4   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f85c19 PathGetObjectInfo(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, short*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char*) + 296
5   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x00007fff82f85a48 FSPathMakeRefInternal(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, FSRef*, unsigned char*) + 114
6   com.apple.Foundation                0x00007fff87799e20 -[NSFileManager directoryContentsAtPath:matchingExtension:options:keepExtension:error:] + 154
7   com.apple.Foundation                0x00007fff87799d84 -[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:] + 35
8   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff86701fc7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 286
9   com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff86701dd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
10  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff866ff35b NSApplicationMain + 279
11  com.apple.calculator                0x0000000100001940 0x100000000 + 6464
```

So, what gives? I am tempted to reboot, but with an issue this severe I worry that the OS might not come back up at all.

Comment: Well, this issue mysteriously cleared itself up after a couple days. Not exactly confidence inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

We have experienced exactly the same symptoms on 10.6 (no new processes can start, and their logs indicate they crash at _SCUniverseGetEntryAddress) on several occasions now. I booted the computer up from the system disc and repaired the boot drive and it seems to be working so far. Another person described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2367248?start=0&tstart=0) that turning off previews for his EyeTV recordings solved his problems.